# Can't paste long cypher text on Neo4j Browser

Tags: neo4j

I use Neo4j the below.

- Neo4j Browser version: 4.0.8
- Neo4j Server version: 3.5.18 (community)

Since about half a year ago, I can't paste long cypher text on Neo4j Browser.
I can paste it per 10 lines in several batches. But I'm going crazy.
I was able to paste long cypher text about half a year ago.
I'm at a loss for finding a solution.

A sample of long cypher text is the following(syntactically correct).

```
MATCH(a0:C_Patent) WHERE a0._SID IN ['the_id']
    CALL apoc.cypher.run('WITH {a0} AS a0 OPTIONAL MATCH(b2:C_Country)  WHERE a0.Country = b2.Name
    OPTIONAL MATCH(b2:C_Country) RETURN b2._SID AS _SID, LABELS(b2)[0] AS module, b2.Name AS Name, b2.CountryName AS CountryName', {a0:a0}) YIELD value AS b2
    WITH DISTINCT a0, {_SID:b2._SID, module:b2.module, Name:b2.Name, CountryName:b2.CountryName} AS Country
    CALL apoc.cypher.run('WITH {a0} AS a0 OPTIONAL MATCH(c2:C_Employee)  WHERE a0.LastModifiedUser = c2.Name
    OPTIONAL MATCH(c2:C_Employee) RETURN c2._SID AS _SID, LABELS(c2)[0] AS module, c2.Name AS Name, c2.Fullname AS Fullname', {a0:a0}) YIELD value AS c2
    WITH DISTINCT a0, Country, {_SID:c2._SID, module:c2.module, Name:c2.Name, Fullname:c2.Fullname} AS LastModifiedUser
OPTIONAL MATCH(a0:C_Patent)-[d0:RDAVAILABLE]->(e0:C_RDDivision)
    WITH DISTINCT a0, Country, LastModifiedUser, {_SID:e0._SID, module:LABELS(e0)[0], _RID:d0._RID, Name:e0.Name, Fullname:e0.Fullname, Name:e0.Name} AS RDDivision ORDER BY RDDivision.Name
OPTIONAL MATCH(a0:C_Patent)-[f0:ATTACHMENT]->(g0:C_Document) WHERE g0.Type = '1'
    WITH DISTINCT a0, Country, LastModifiedUser, RDDivision, {_SID:g0._SID, module:LABELS(g0)[0], _RID:f0._RID, Name:g0.Name, Date:g0.Date, Time:g0.Time} AS PrincipalFigure ORDER BY PrincipalFigure.Date ASC, PrincipalFigure.Time ASC
OPTIONAL MATCH(a0:C_Patent)-[h0:APPLICANT]->(i0) WHERE (i0:C_Company OR i0:C_Party OR i0:C_Person OR i0:C_Practitioner)
    WITH DISTINCT a0, Country, LastModifiedUser, RDDivision, PrincipalFigure, {_SID:i0._SID, module:LABELS(i0)[0], _RID:h0._RID, RightShare:h0.RightShare, CostShare:h0.CostShare, ApplicantReference:h0.ApplicantReference, Type:h0.Type, ApplicantMemo:h0.ApplicantMemo, Order:h0.Order, Name:i0.Name, Fullname:i0.Fullname, Order:h0.Order} AS Applicants ORDER BY Applicants.Order ASC
OPTIONAL MATCH(a0:C_Patent)-[j0:REPRESENTOR]->(k0) WHERE (k0:C_Company OR k0:C_Party)
    WITH DISTINCT a0, Country, LastModifiedUser, RDDivision, PrincipalFigure, Applicants, {_SID:k0._SID, module:LABELS(k0)[0], _RID:j0._RID, ApplicantReference:j0.ApplicantReference, ApplicantMemo:j0.ApplicantMemo, Order:j0.Order, Name:k0.Name, Fullname:k0.Fullname, Order:j0.Order} AS Representor ORDER BY Representor.Order ASC
CALL apoc.path.spanningTree(a0, {relationshipFilter: 'ORIGINAL|PRIORITY|REGIONAL', labelFilter: '+C_Design|C_Gazette|C_Patent', minLevel: 0, maxLevel: 999}) YIELD path
    WITH DISTINCT a0, Country, LastModifiedUser, RDDivision, PrincipalFigure, Applicants, Representor, Inventors, NODES(path) AS _nodes UNWIND _nodes AS _node
    OPTIONAL MATCH(_node)-[r:ORIGINAL|PRIORITY|REGIONAL]-(dst)
    WITH DISTINCT a0, Country, LastModifiedUser, RDDivision, PrincipalFigure, Applicants, Representor, Inventors, _node, r, dst, _node=STARTNODE(r) AS outgoing ORDER BY _node.Name
    WITH DISTINCT a0, Country, LastModifiedUser, RDDivision, PrincipalFigure, Applicants, Representor, Inventors, _node, CASE WHEN outgoing THEN { type:TYPE(r), _SID:dst._SID } END AS parents
    WITH DISTINCT a0, Country, LastModifiedUser, RDDivision, PrincipalFigure, Applicants, Representor, Inventors, _node {._SID, `#parents`:COLLECT(parents), .Name, ._SID, .Status, .Country, .Law, .AppType, .AppRoute, .AppNumber, .AppDate, .PubNumber, .RegNumber, .RegDate, module:LABELS(_node)[0]} AS LegalFamily
OPTIONAL MATCH(a0:C_Patent)-[t0:AGENT]->(u0) WHERE (u0:C_Employee OR u0:C_Party OR u0:C_Person OR u0:C_Practitioner)
    OPTIONAL MATCH(u0)-[v0:COMPANY]->(w0) WHERE (w0:C_Company OR w0:C_Party OR w0:C_Practitioner)
    WITH DISTINCT a0, Country, LastModifiedUser, RDDivision, PrincipalFigure, Applicants, Representor, Inventors, LegalFamily, {_SID:u0._SID, module:LABELS(u0)[0], _RID:t0._RID, Type:t0.Type, AgentMemo:t0.AgentMemo, Order:t0.Order, Name:u0.Name, Fullname:u0.Fullname, ComName:w0.Fullname, Order:t0.Order} AS Practitioners ORDER BY Practitioners.Order ASC
OPTIONAL MATCH(a0:C_Patent)-[x0:IPREP]->(y0:C_Employee)
    WITH DISTINCT a0, Country, LastModifiedUser, RDDivision, PrincipalFigure, Applicants, Representor, Inventors, LegalFamily, Practitioners, {`@IPRepFullname`:y0.Fullname, Name:y0.Name} AS y0_Pack ORDER BY y0_Pack.Name
OPTIONAL MATCH(a0:C_Patent)-[z0:REPCONTACT]->(a1:C_Employee)
    WITH DISTINCT a0, Country, LastModifiedUser, RDDivision, PrincipalFigure, Applicants, Representor, Inventors, LegalFamily, Practitioners, y0_Pack, {`@ContactFullname`:a1.Fullname, Name:a1.Name} AS a1_Pack ORDER BY a1_Pack.Name
OPTIONAL MATCH(a0:C_Patent)-[b1:INVENTOR]->(c1) WHERE (c1:C_Employee OR c1:C_Person) AND b1.Order = 1
    WITH DISTINCT a0, Country, LastModifiedUser, RDDivision, PrincipalFigure, Applicants, Representor, Inventors, LegalFamily, Practitioners, y0_Pack, a1_Pack, {`@RepInventorFullname`:c1.Fullname, Name:c1.Name} AS c1_Pack ORDER BY c1_Pack.Name
OPTIONAL MATCH(a0:C_Patent)-[d1:RIGHTSHARE]->(e1:C_Office)
    WITH DISTINCT a0, Country, LastModifiedUser, RDDivision, PrincipalFigure, Applicants, Representor, Inventors, LegalFamily, Practitioners, y0_Pack, a1_Pack, c1_Pack, {`@RightDivisionFullnames`:e1.Fullname, _SID:e1._SID, Order:d1.Order} AS e1_Pack ORDER BY e1_Pack.Order ASC
OPTIONAL MATCH(a0:C_Patent)-[f1:COSTSHARE]->(g1:C_CostShare)
    WITH DISTINCT a0, Country, LastModifiedUser, RDDivision, PrincipalFigure, Applicants, Representor, Inventors, LegalFamily, Practitioners, y0_Pack, a1_Pack, c1_Pack, e1_Pack, {`@CostDivisionFullnames`:g1.Fullname, _SID:g1._SID, Order:f1.Order} AS g1_Pack ORDER BY g1_Pack.Order ASC
OPTIONAL MATCH(a0:C_Patent)<-[h1:APPLICATION]-(i1:C_PatFamily)
    WITH DISTINCT a0, Country, LastModifiedUser, RDDivision, PrincipalFigure, Applicants, Representor, Inventors, LegalFamily, Practitioners, y0_Pack, a1_Pack, c1_Pack, e1_Pack, g1_Pack, {`@FamilyNo`:i1.Name, Name:i1.Name} AS i1_Pack ORDER BY i1_Pack.Name
OPTIONAL MATCH(a0:C_Patent)-[j1:ORIGINAL|PRIORITY|REGIONAL*0..]->(k1)-[l1:PRIORITY]->(m1) WHERE (k1:C_Gazette OR k1:C_Patent) AND (m1:C_Gazette OR m1:C_Patent) AND NOT (m1)-[:PRIORITY]->()
    WITH DISTINCT a0, Country, LastModifiedUser, RDDivision, PrincipalFigure, Applicants, Representor, Inventors, LegalFamily, Practitioners, y0_Pack, a1_Pack, c1_Pack, e1_Pack, g1_Pack, i1_Pack
    , MIN({AppDate:m1.AppDate, Name:m1.Name}) AS _min
    OPTIONAL MATCH(a0:C_Patent)-[j1:ORIGINAL|PRIORITY|REGIONAL*0..]->(k1)-[l1:PRIORITY]->(m1)
    WHERE NOT (m1)-[:PRIORITY]->() AND _min.AppDate = m1.AppDate AND _min.Name = m1.Name
    WITH DISTINCT a0, Country, LastModifiedUser, RDDivision, PrincipalFigure, Applicants, Representor, Inventors, LegalFamily, Practitioners, y0_Pack, a1_Pack, c1_Pack, e1_Pack, g1_Pack, i1_Pack, {`@EarliestPriorityClaimAppDate`:m1.AppDate, Name:k1.Name} AS m1_Pack ORDER BY m1_Pack.Name
OPTIONAL MATCH(a0:C_Patent)-[n1:ORIGINAL*0..]->(o1)-[p1:ORIGINAL]->(q1) WHERE (o1:C_Design OR o1:C_Gazette OR o1:C_Patent) AND (q1:C_Design OR q1:C_Gazette OR q1:C_Patent) AND NOT (q1)-[:ORIGINAL]->()
    WITH DISTINCT a0, Country, LastModifiedUser, RDDivision, PrincipalFigure, Applicants, Representor, Inventors, LegalFamily, Practitioners, y0_Pack, a1_Pack, c1_Pack, e1_Pack, g1_Pack, i1_Pack, m1_Pack
    , MIN({AppDate:q1.AppDate, Name:q1.Name}) AS _min
    OPTIONAL MATCH(a0:C_Patent)-[n1:ORIGINAL*0..]->(o1)-[p1:ORIGINAL]->(q1)
    WHERE NOT (q1)-[:ORIGINAL]->() AND _min.AppDate = q1.AppDate AND _min.Name = q1.Name
    WITH DISTINCT a0, Country, LastModifiedUser, RDDivision, PrincipalFigure, Applicants, Representor, Inventors, LegalFamily, Practitioners, y0_Pack, a1_Pack, c1_Pack, e1_Pack, g1_Pack, i1_Pack, m1_Pack, {`@EarliestParentAppDate`:q1.AppDate, Name:o1.Name} AS q1_Pack ORDER BY q1_Pack.Name
OPTIONAL MATCH(a0:C_Patent)-[r1:APPOFFICE]->(s1) WHERE (s1:C_Company OR s1:C_Party OR s1:C_Practitioner)
    WITH DISTINCT a0, Country, LastModifiedUser, RDDivision, PrincipalFigure, Applicants, Representor, Inventors, LegalFamily, Practitioners, y0_Pack, a1_Pack, c1_Pack, e1_Pack, g1_Pack, i1_Pack, m1_Pack, q1_Pack, {`@SupplierFullname`:s1.Fullname, Name:s1.Name} AS s1_Pack ORDER BY s1_Pack.Name
OPTIONAL MATCH(a0:C_Patent)-[t1:ASSOCIATOR]->(u1:C_Practitioner)
    WITH DISTINCT a0, Country, LastModifiedUser, RDDivision, PrincipalFigure, Applicants, Representor, Inventors, LegalFamily, Practitioners, y0_Pack, a1_Pack, c1_Pack, e1_Pack, g1_Pack, i1_Pack, m1_Pack, q1_Pack, s1_Pack, {`@AssociatorFullname`:u1.Fullname, Name:u1.Name} AS u1_Pack ORDER BY u1_Pack.Name
OPTIONAL MATCH(a0:C_Patent)-[v1:AVAILABLE]->(w1:C_Product)
    WITH DISTINCT a0, Country, LastModifiedUser, RDDivision, PrincipalFigure, Applicants, Representor, Inventors, LegalFamily, Practitioners, y0_Pack, a1_Pack, c1_Pack, e1_Pack, g1_Pack, i1_Pack, m1_Pack, q1_Pack, s1_Pack, u1_Pack, {`@ProductFullnames`:w1.Fullname, _SID:w1._SID, Order:v1.Order} AS w1_Pack ORDER BY w1_Pack.Order ASC
OPTIONAL MATCH(a0:C_Patent)-[x1:PRIORITY|REGIONAL*0..]->(y1)-[z1:REGIONAL]->(a2) WHERE (y1:C_Gazette OR y1:C_Patent) AND (a2:C_Gazette OR a2:C_Patent) AND (a0.Country = 'WO' OR a2.Country = 'WO')
    WITH DISTINCT a0, Country, LastModifiedUser, RDDivision, PrincipalFigure, Applicants, Representor, Inventors, LegalFamily, Practitioners, y0_Pack, a1_Pack, c1_Pack, e1_Pack, g1_Pack, i1_Pack, m1_Pack, q1_Pack, s1_Pack, u1_Pack, w1_Pack, {`@IntlAppDate`:CASE WHEN a0.Country = 'WO' THEN a0.AppDate ELSE a2.AppDate END, `@IntlPubDate`:CASE WHEN a0.Country = 'WO' THEN a0.PubDate ELSE a2.PubDate END, Name:y1.Name} AS a2_Pack ORDER BY a2_Pack.Name
RETURN labels(a0)[0] AS label, a0{_SID:a0._SID, module:labels(a0)[0], public:1
, _SID:a0._SID
, Name:a0.Name
, Status:a0.Status
, AppNumber:a0.AppNumber
, InventionTitle:a0.InventionTitle
, Contracted:a0.Contracted
, NEDOContracted:a0.NEDOContracted
, Finally:a0.Finally
, Nickname:a0.Nickname
, AppDate:a0.AppDate
, PubNumber:a0.PubNumber
, PubDate:a0.PubDate
, ExamRequestDeadline:a0.ExamRequestDeadline
, NextAnnuityDueDate:a0.NextAnnuityDueDate
, RegNumber:a0.RegNumber
, RegDate:a0.RegDate
, FinallyDate:a0.FinallyDate
, TermRemainingDays:duration.inDays(date(), date(toString(a0.PatentTermLapseDate))).days
, SupplierAssignedID:a0.SupplierAssignedID
, Evaluation:a0.Evaluation
, Rank:a0.Rank
, IPContactClass:a0.IPContactClass
, IssueMemo:a0.IssueMemo
, ExpenseMemo:a0.ExpenseMemo
, ApplicationTitle:a0.ApplicationTitle
, ClaimCount:a0.ClaimCount
, ClaimCountInApp:a0.ClaimCountInApp
, AppReference:a0.AppReference
, Abstract:a0.Abstract
, Claims:a0.Claims
, IPC:a0.IPC
, ApplicationNote:a0.ApplicationNote
, AppKeyword:a0.AppKeyword
, FreeKeyward:a0.FreeKeyward
, ApplicationMemo:a0.ApplicationMemo
, ResearchDevelopmentDivision:a0.ResearchDevelopmentDivision
, ResearchDevelopmentDivisionText:a0.ResearchDevelopmentDivisionText
, ResearchDevelopmentDivision_SDK:a0.ResearchDevelopmentDivision_SDK
, ResearchDevelopmentDivisionText_SDK:a0.ResearchDevelopmentDivisionText_SDK
, m_FamilyNo:a0.m_FamilyNo
, m_OrgName:a0.m_OrgName
, OrgCompany:a0.OrgCompany
, m_Knowhow:a0.m_Knowhow
, LastModifiedTime:a0.LastModifiedTime
, CreatedTime:a0.CreatedTime
, Law:a0.Law
, AppRoute:a0.AppRoute
, Country:COLLECT(Country)[0]
, LastModifiedUser:COLLECT(LastModifiedUser)[0]
, RDDivision:CASE WHEN RDDivision._SID IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE COLLECT(DISTINCT RDDivision)[0] END
, PrincipalFigure:CASE WHEN PrincipalFigure._SID IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE COLLECT(DISTINCT PrincipalFigure)[0] END
, Applicants:CASE WHEN Applicants._SID IS NULL THEN [] ELSE COLLECT(DISTINCT Applicants) END
, Representor:CASE WHEN Representor._SID IS NULL THEN [] ELSE COLLECT(DISTINCT Representor) END
, Inventors:CASE WHEN Inventors._SID IS NULL THEN [] ELSE COLLECT(DISTINCT Inventors) END
, LegalFamily:CASE WHEN LegalFamily._SID IS NULL THEN [] ELSE COLLECT(DISTINCT LegalFamily) END
, Practitioners:CASE WHEN Practitioners._SID IS NULL THEN [] ELSE COLLECT(DISTINCT Practitioners) END
, IPRepFullname:COLLECT(DISTINCT y0_Pack.`@IPRepFullname`)
, ContactFullname:COLLECT(DISTINCT a1_Pack.`@ContactFullname`)
, RepInventorFullname:COLLECT(DISTINCT c1_Pack.`@RepInventorFullname`)
, RightDivisionFullnames:REDUCE(a=[], x IN COLLECT(DISTINCT {_SID:e1_Pack._SID, `@RightDivisionFullnames`:e1_Pack.`@RightDivisionFullnames`}) | a + COALESCE(x.`@RightDivisionFullnames`, 'null'))
, CostDivisionFullnames:REDUCE(a=[], x IN COLLECT(DISTINCT {_SID:g1_Pack._SID, `@CostDivisionFullnames`:g1_Pack.`@CostDivisionFullnames`}) | a + COALESCE(x.`@CostDivisionFullnames`, 'null'))
, FamilyNo:COLLECT(DISTINCT i1_Pack.`@FamilyNo`)
, EarliestPriorityClaimAppDate:COLLECT(DISTINCT m1_Pack.`@EarliestPriorityClaimAppDate`)
, EarliestParentAppDate:COLLECT(DISTINCT q1_Pack.`@EarliestParentAppDate`)
, SupplierFullname:COLLECT(DISTINCT s1_Pack.`@SupplierFullname`)
, AssociatorFullname:COLLECT(DISTINCT u1_Pack.`@AssociatorFullname`)
, ProductFullnames:REDUCE(a=[], x IN COLLECT(DISTINCT {_SID:w1_Pack._SID, `@ProductFullnames`:w1_Pack.`@ProductFullnames`}) | a + COALESCE(x.`@ProductFullnames`, 'null'))
, IntlAppDate:COLLECT(DISTINCT a2_Pack.`@IntlAppDate`)
, IntlPubDate:COLLECT(DISTINCT a2_Pack.`@IntlPubDate`)
} AS nodes ORDER BY nodes.Name DESC;
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: No errors. I just can't paste cypher text on Neo4j browser.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try out the centrally hosted browser and see if the latest versions sorts things out for you.  FWIW, I couldn't replicate the issue on the latest version of Browser (5.3.0)

http://browser.graphapp.io

Comment: I have upgraded my Neo4j Server to version: 4.4.16 and Neo4j Browser to version: 5.3.0. but nothing changed.